# Pymongo Bulk Delete

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulk, bulk-delete

I need to use pymongo to do bulk delete for mongodb. I'm getting the _id field of the documents that I need deleted with a query but I'm not able to figure out how to use the _id's I get to be deleted in chunks of 10,000.

Comment: Please include some code and maybe what the db looks like so we can help you better. Have you also tried looking at the docs? possibly [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) would be down your alley.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example of [Unordered Bulk Write Operations](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations) using current [PyMongo v3.7.2](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.7.2/#pymongo-release-documentation):

```
from pymongo import DeleteOne
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError

requests = [
        DeleteOne({'_id': 101}),
        DeleteOne({'_id': 102})]
try:
    db.collection.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    pprint(bwe.details)
```

The example above is using the `unordered` operations, because unordered bulk operations are batched and sent to the server in arbitrary order where they may be executed in **parallel**. Any errors that occur are reported after all operations are attempted. See also [PyMongo Bulk Write Operations](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#) and [MongoDB Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) for more information.

Comment: I have tried this but seems it's not working I found when use DeleteOne we should ```from bson import ObjectId``` and : ```DeleteOne({'_id': ObjectId(101)})```